# Combining of object and type any - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to combine `topic_subscription` with `default_subscription` in my locals.tf
In our code we created a variable of type `any` looking as followed;

```
variable "topic_subscription" {
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}
```

This will allow adding a multitude of subscription types to our SNS topic.

```
topic_subscription = {
  departmenta = {
    endpoint = "a@b.com",
    protocol = "email"
  },
  departmentc = {
    endpoint = "c@d.com",
    protocol = "email" 
  }
}
```

And use it within a `for.each` setup;

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "this" {
  for_each = var.topic_subscription

  endpoint  = each.value["endpoint"]  
  protocol  = each.value["protocol"]  
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.this.arn
}
```

In the locals.tf is there a solution to combine topic_subscription with a default_subscription map/object?

```
locals {
  default_subscription = {
    endpoint = "x@y.com",
    protocol = "email"
  }

  combined_subscription = ???? var.topic_subscription + local.default_subscription ????
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

== Update on definition on combine ==

If it's created as followed (hardcoded) it works, so 'combining' the variable and the local to look as followed.

```
combined_subscription = {
  departmenta = {
    endpoint = "a@b.com",
    protocol = "email"
  },
  departmentc = {
    endpoint = "c@d.com",
    protocol = "email"
  }
  default_subscription = {
    endpoint = "x@y.com",
    protocol = "email"
  }
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: Add example of the combined_subscription I'm looking for, (or suggestions how it could work to but different)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about merging two maps together: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html

Comment: Have tried a few variations of that, including concat/zipmap But am not able to get to the combined_subscription object.

Comment: It definitely returns the value you desired according to your question with the correct inputs, so you may need to update with how its behavior deviates from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First I think an important thing to note here is that there aren't really "values of type `any`" in Terraform. Instead, a variable with `type = any` means that the type is *unconstrained*, which is to say that Terraform will decide dynamically what the type is based on what the caller passes in.

With that said then, your example value here is an object type. If we were to write it out as an explicit type constraint, without an `any` wildcard, it would look like this:

```
  type = object({
    departmenta = object({
      endpoint = string
      protocol = string
    })
    departmentc = object({
      endpoint = string
      protocol = string
    })
  })
```

Terraform is, in effect, dynamically replacing your `any` with the above when evaluating the variable value, and so inside your module you can use this value with any operation that makes sense with a value of this type.

[The `merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html), when given object-typed values, produces a new value of an object type which merges the two object types together by their unique attribute names. In your case, it seems that you want to construct a new value whose object type includes an additional `default_subscription` attribute whose value matches `local.default_subscription`.

Here's one way to achieve that, using `merge`:

```
variable "topic_subscription" {
  type    = any
  default = {}
}

locals {
  default_subscription = {
    endpoint = "x@y.com",
    protocol = "email"
  }

  combined_subscription = merge(
    { default_subscription = local.default_subscription },
    var.topic_subscription,
  )
}
```

With the `merge` argument ordering I wrote above, the caller could provide its own `default_subscription` attribute that would override the one given inside the module. If you don't want that to be true then you could either invert the two arguments (making the module-defined `default_subscription` take precedence) or you could write a validation rule that prohibits the caller from setting `default_subscription` altogether:

```
variable "topic_subscription" {
  type    = any
  default = {}

  validation {
    condition     = !can(var.topic_subscription.default_subscription)
    error_message = "The topic subscription key \"default_subscription\" is reserved for this module's own use."
  }
}
```